# images in imageview get background color

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I have an adapter that returns the list of my products, It has an `ImageView` inside and I'm using Glide for downloading the images

this is the result :
[image]

as you can see, the image gets a background colour, the main image is like this :

[image]

as you can see, the main image on the server has no background.

this is my xml code :

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

this is my java code:

```
Glide.with(ctx).load(ctx.getString(R.string.url) + "Opitures/" + img).into(viewHolder.img);
```

how can I remove the background?

Comment: set transparent background to ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Making background color transparent should work

Using xml: android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Using JAVA: viewHolder.img.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));